# How to test expect().toHaveBeenCalled() - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to test that my external function has been called, but I don't seem to figure it out...

I am currently getting the fail message:

> **Expected spy login to have been called.**

**TEST**

```
fit('should login with valid form & credentials', inject([AuthService],
        (authServ: AuthService) => {
        component.onSubmit(validFormGoodCreds);
        spy = spyOn(authServ, 'login');

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(hideMsg).toEqual(true);
    }));
```

**Login component**

```
...
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.authService.login(this.user.username, this.user.password)
      .subscribe(
          data => {
            /* TODO: Navigate to holding page etc */
            // Hide any error message that was previously shown
            this.hideErrorMsg = true;
          },
          err => {
            // Change error message to be shown
            this.errorMessage = 'Either username or password were incorrect';
            // Show the error message
            this.hideErrorMsg = false;
          }
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spy = spyOn(authServ, 'login').and.returnValue(true); 
expect(authServ.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This is a good testing guide for Angular 5+: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/

Comment: I can see what should be happening and why this should happen, I just can't get it to work at the moment. I will get somebody else in my team to take a look at it. Find out I'm a total n00b.